# Boolean Parenthesization Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm working on the following algorithm out of Cracking The Coding Interview:

> Given a boolean expression containing the symbols {true, false, and,
>   or, xor}, count the number of ways to parenthesize the expression such
>   that it evaluates to true.

The author details a recursive solution of placing parenthesis at each operator char. So for example, if expression is 1^0^0|1 then placing at char = 1 would be (1)^(0^0|1).

She does this for every operator char i from 1 to n, where the two expressions are from 0 to i and i + 1 to n, and then calls the recursive function on each substring.

Here's what I don't understand. For example, 1^(0^0)|1 this expression is excluded from this process. Why is that? Isn't this also important to be considered?

Comment: Assuming left-associativity, that can be obtained by the process `(1^0^0)|(1) --> ((1)^(0^0))|(1)`

Comment: If you allow redundant parentheses, the answer is either zero or infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 ^ (0 ^ 0) | 1` is the same as `(1 ^ (0 ^ 0)) | (1)`.

Since you mentioned that the parantheses are inserted *recursively*, nothing is left out:

```
    1 ^ 0 ^ 0 | 1
    |
    +--(1) ^ (0 ^ 0 | 1)
    |  +--(1) ^ ((0 ^ 0) | 1)
    |  +--(1) ^ (0 ^ (0 | 1))
    |
    +--(1 ^ 0) ^ (0 | 1)
    |
    +--(1 ^ 0 ^ 0) | (1)
       +--((1 ^ 0) ^ 0) | (1)
       +--(1 ^ (0 ^ 0)) | (1)    ← here it is
```